# Run Test Payments in Production environment with Stripe Payment Extension for Firebase

Tags: stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

My web site is live using a production version of Stripe Payment Extension for Firebase.

How can continue running tests without impacting my customers?
I can create test cloud functions using stripe test keys and test webhook keys, but what about the Stripe Firebase Extension configuration ? If I change Stripe Keys and Webhook keys to their test versions it will prevent customers from purchasing. What is the work around ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should always keep your test environment separate from the production. My advise is to create another Firebase project and configure its Firebase extension with the test mode API key and webhook secret.